# Retrieve separate values from an array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa

I have a variable which is printing its value on console like this:

> source id key is (
>
> ```
>    {
>
>    name = "ABC Rawal";
>
>    uid = 10000048171452;
> ```
>
> }
>   )

This is the code I'm using to do that:

```
-(void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result {

    NSLog(@"source id key is %@", result);

}
```

I have to get `name` and `uid` separately. How can I retrieve those value from `result`?

Comment: we can't know for sure since you are not showing the definition of the class of `result`. It could be a dictionary in that case it would be: `NSString *name = [result objectForKey:@"name"]; ` and `int uid = [[result objectForKey:@"uid"] intValue];` but I am just guessing.

Comment: Inside of function there is one statement like NSArray* users = result; so I think result is NSArray variable.

Comment: @nacho The output is either a string (unlikely) or an array. Notice the parentheses — they’re the NeXTSTEP representation of an array, and the one used by `-[NSArray description]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`result` is an array comprised of dictionaries. In your example, the array has only one element.

If you want only the first element in the array, then:

```
if ([result count] > 0) {
    NSDictionary *person = [result objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *personName = [person objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *personUID = [person objectForKey:@"uid"];
    …
}
```

Or, if you want to iterate over all elements in the array — in case the array has more than one element — then:

```
for (NSDictionary *person in result) {
    NSString *personName = [person objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *personUID = [person objectForKey:@"uid"];
    …    
}
```

Note that from your output it’s not possible to know whether `uid` is a string or a number. The code above considers it’s a string; in case it’s a number, use:

```
NSInteger personUID = [[person objectForKey:@"uid"] integerValue];
```

or an appropriate integer type that can hold the range of possible values.